# In python, how can I evenly distribute elements of list1 over elements of list2 without any shared elements?

Tags: python, list, append, distribute

Let's say I have

```
list1=['a','b']
```

and

```
list2=['d','c','e','f']
```

How can I join them into a third list without any two elements of `list1` sharing an element of `list2`?

Like this:

```
list3=['ad','bc','ae','bf']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some nifty itertools tricks to achieve your result. Primarily, you want to zip both the lists, but as the former is shorter , you want to continue until you exhaust it

```
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle
>>> list1=['a','b']
>>> list2=['d','c','e','f']
>>> map(''.join, list(izip(cycle(list1), list2)))
['ad', 'bc', 'ae', 'bf']
```

I am using python 3.4.2 ,
 and I am on windows 7

Comment: Error: Cannot import name izip

Comment: @MMG: Please state your Python's version